# Add or remove suffix to image URLS in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, url, append

I am looking for the code required to use on a .click function. I have a theme switcher dark, light, and I would like to add _dark to all image urls within a certain div (.the-images) when clicking the dark and remove _dark from the image URL when clicking light.

So the url would be lalalalala.jpg by default or in light, but lalalalala_dark.jpg when clicking dark.

To clarify there are about 20 images in the .the-images div. They all have different URLs but I would like to add to the click function so that _dark is added to the url before .jpg when clicking dark.

**UPDATE**

So I was helpfully recommended to put the dark images in a /dark directory so I need only change part of the URL. There are various examples of these images being used around the website but always in a div called 'the-images'.

So the code would need to be

```
$(".light").click(function() {
 ### needs /images/name.png for all images in "the-images" div ###
}

$(".dark").click(function() {
 ### needs /images/dark/name.png for all images in "the-images" div ###
}
```

This would be what I would need in my code now. Thanks for all the help

This was marked as duplicate by some others but I do not see any questions referring to how to change part of multiple image urls that are within a specified div. Thank you. To clarify I already have the style switcher in place (the body class toggles dark and light based on user click). I now need to find a way for all of the images in 'the-images' (of which there are 20+) to be in the /dark directory if the dark theme is on. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post what you've already tried?

Answer (score 0):

#### JavaScript Only Solution

If all the images are in `img` for example would to have all the `dark` images in `img/dark` and just change the relative path instead of the filename.

```
var normal = "img/icon-1.png"
console.log(normal)
var dark = normal.replace('img/','img/dark/')
console.log(dark)
```

This is a naive way of how *themeing* can be done wuth just JavaScript.

#### JavaScript and CSS Solution

```html
<img class="normal" src="img/icon-1.jpg" />
```

```css
.normal {
  content: url(img/icon-1.jpg);
}

.dark{
  content: url(img/dark/icon-1.jpg);
}
```

Then you just change the class with JavaScript.

#### To do all images in a specific `<div>`

Use the appropriate selector, select the `<div>` you want and loop through the resulting `<img>` tags and replace the `normal` class with `dark`.

Something like this:

```
function theme(fromTheme,toTheme) {
    $('.target-div').children('img').map(function(){
        $(this).addClass(fromTheme);
        $(this).removeClass(toTheme);
    });
}
```